# Using L2CAP on STM32L4 + BlueNRG

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, l2cap

I'm new to BLE and I am confused with the L2CAP protocol. I've read the Bluetooth Core specification related to L2CAP and I understood that it provides in particular Segmentation and Retransmission capability. I've also found in STM32CubeL4 some code to implement the L2CAP related commands like Connection parameter Update Request.

What I don't understand is:
- is the L2CAP protocol fully implemented in the software provided by STMicro ? I didn't find the drivers or HAL doing that.
- how is the SAR functionality enabled by the Central host and the Peripheral host ?

Answer (score 1):

BlueNRG is a BLE network processor. The BLE protocol stack is implemented in the embedded Cortex-M0 microprocessor, including L2CAP SAR functions.

The application processor (STM32L4 in this case) can only perform limited L2CAP functions through the SPI based proprietary interface, called ACI, connecting to the network processor (BlueNRG).
ACI can be regarded as an enhancement to Bluetooth HCI.

[image: ACI]

For the available ACIs, please refer to: [UM1865](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00162667.pdf)